# App isn't loading recent activity

Tags: bug, android-app, activity-summary

In the Android App, the profile screen (reached by the hamburger button -> profile name) isn't loading recent activity.

Usually it loads recent comments/posts under "Your recent activity", but nothing shows up.

I'm reading about server problems, but it seems like they're supposed to be resolved by now?

And I've tried loading it from different networks, and restarting my phone. I have no reason to believe this is on my end.

- App Version: 1.0.95
- Device Manufacturer: samsung
- Device Model: SM-N950W
- OS Version: 8.0.0 (N950WVLS5CRG9)

---

An hour into this morning, the activity history kinda started working. It's showing some posts, but also skipping some posts that I know weren't deleted.

---

Broken again after having worked yesterday.

Comment: Looks like you're reporting 2 bug reports: the profile screen, and the activity feed? FWIW, the profile screen just loads using the same SE API, and the activity feed is generated exclusively (I don't know the exact algorithm) and might not cover all activities...

Comment: @Somewhat No. Just the page I mentioned in the first paragraph. I'll change the wording.