# Where is all the [activity]?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, retag-request, synonym-request

Currently there are multiple tags in regard to the same thing, the [activity tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=activity) of a user profile.

There are:

1. [activity](/questions/tagged/activity)
2. [recent-activity](/questions/tagged/recent-activity)
3. [activity-summary](/questions/tagged/activity-summary)

With the following excerpts:

1. Use this tag for questions about the activity tab. The activity tab is found in the user profile and gives access to several categories.
2. Every user's account profile has a section showing the recent reviews, revisions, comments, badges, posts (questions and answers), and accepts.
3. There is no usage guidance for this tag … yet!

Of these three tags, only [activity](/questions/tagged/activity) has a filled [tag info](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/activity/info), it reads as follows:

> In your user profile you'll find the
>   [activity](/users/current?tab=activity) tab.
>
> Use this tag if you have a question about the information, user
>   interaction, data source, layout, including any of the sub-tabs:
>
> - summary
> - answers
> - questions
> - reputation
> - badges
> - favorites
> - all actions
> - responses
> - votes
>
> Questions about the [activity-summary](/questions/tagged/activity-summary) should be tagged as such.

This makes me believe that the [activity-summary](/questions/tagged/activity-summary) should only be used for questions regarding the first [sub-tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=summary) of the activity tab. The questions using this tag how-ever don't comply to that principle. For example the three most recent question: [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100059/problem-displaying-title-revisions-on-profile-activity-tab), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/321353/mul-ti-ple-plu-ral-iza-tion-bugs-on-the-user-ac-tiv-ity-page-on-at-least-the-s), [3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316340/app-isnt-loading-recent-activity) use this tag to indicate the overall activity tab of a user profile.

For [recent-activity](/questions/tagged/recent-activity) the same thing is taking place. Examples: [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333800/what-happens-to-activity-logs-related-to-deleted-questions), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332074/persistence-of-already-viewed-activity-changes-on-the-profile-page), [3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179031/how-can-i-find-answers-ive-downvoted). They all describe a problem with the activity tab of a user profile.

**Can we rename / synonym-ize all these tags into** [activity-tab](/questions/tagged/activity-tab)**?**
As there currently isn't a great deal of difference in how these tags are used I think we are better off using just one tag. Preferably I'd rename [activity](/questions/tagged/activity) into [activity-tab](/questions/tagged/activity-tab) and make the other two synonyms of it.

Comment: It seems like [activity-summary] refers to the "Summary" page of the "Activity" page of a user profile, whereas the [activity] tag wiki seems to be talking about the overall "Activity" page itself. The scope/focus of [recent-activity] seems to be a bit less clear, however; the tag excerpt seems to indicate that it might refer to the "All actions" tab of the "Activity" page, but I'm less sure of that.

Comment: @V2Blast FWIW, that is how I interpret the scopes of these three tags as well.

Comment: Another tag with a vague name and no tag wiki: \[[tag:active]\]. (There's also \[[tag:question-activity]\], which may end up getting merged into \[[tag:last-activity]\] by a mod – which might get renamed by the community as well due to the [upcoming change to the "Active" wording at the top of question pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376296/335251)...)